# Plone: Simplesocial like button issue

Tags: plone, diazo

I need to use the collective.simplesozial on a site.

Through the rules I copied the portlet div into the site:

```
<after css:theme="#content" css:content="#viewlet-below-content" />
```

I tried to get the ploneonly package and the default package onto the site, but nothing helped out. (The default package is always on).

```
iframe.js
simplesocial.js
simplesocial_fanpage_post.js
```

are successfully included. I don't get any JS errors.

The Likebutton is enabled.

Does anyone have an idea what could be missing, or what could be wrong?

jQuery version is 1.7.2
Plone version 4.2

Comment: You never actually say what's wrong. Is it not displaying? If not, is it in the source view? Does it show up if you bypass diazo?

Comment: Actually there's one line of code. But nothing happens with it. There should be an iframe and so on. <like ... > gets copied, but nothing happens to it.

Comment: Do you mean that you can see the "one line of code" in the rendered page? If so, crank up firebug and look for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I get. The problem is that there aren't any JS errors...

Comment: Is this working when you bypass Diazo?

Comment: What do you mean by bypass? It works in the backend. It doesn't matter which package I include in the registry. Nothing happens.